# Installment payments online

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, billing, recurring-billing

Paypal allows me to use installment plans with up to 4 installment payments per month. My company selling quite expensive software, so we want to make clients available to make 12 installment payments per year (one payment every month). Maybe someone can offer some other online services, or some other solution for this. We can make recurring payment profile, but user can cancel it anytime. It can be painful, especialy if he bought more than one product.

Btw, sorry for my english.

Comment: IMHO, that sounds like the risk associated with such model. Even in real world, that situation occurs (that's why there are "collection agencies"). The concept of "guaranteed payment" doesn't really apply, unless full payment is obtained...

Comment: It would help to know what country you are building this in; installment payments (and guaranteed installment payments in particular) are very uncommon & generally unsupported in many countries (except as explicit credit programs, ie loans) but are very popular in certain countries; PayPal and other companies have country-specific solutions in some of these markets (e.g. Brazil).

Comment: Well, we are selling software worldwide, so there is no specific country. But thank you for your thoughts. Like you said, installment payments are uncommon solution, so I think we will go subscription way.

Comment: Btw, how adobe.com made theyr annual plan, prepaid monthly? And when you wanna cancel it, they can charge 50% of total price. This is exact what we want to do.

Comment: @geewiz, which are theses country-specifi solutions? I was trying to make a installment payment but I didn't find an option within REST API

Answer (score 0):

I made a bit deeper 'research'. Adobe is using recurly, and paypal payments pro also offering similar service. So there is no 100% secure way to make installment payments without some 'loan agency'. There always are some risks if customer block recurring payments directly from his bank account or smth like that. But in our case, we selling our software to reliable companies, so paypal/recurly is pretty good for us.